# Fixed navbar only with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

As i said i the title, i wanna make a web page with fixed navbar in **aside**.

*(I know how to make it in the top of document)*.

So i tried 2-3 layout *(**Flexbox** and **Columns**)*.

But with neither of them i couldn't make it work perfectly.

This is my *test* code, although you can see it in
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lwo3mcb/)

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var navs = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
   var heigh = $("header:first").outerHeight();
   var wid = $("nav:first").width();
   if (wid != $(window).width() && document.body.scrollTop >= heigh)
   {
    navs.style.position = "fixed";
    $("nav").css("top","0");
   }
   else
    navs.style.position = "relative";
  });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
  html, body {
   font-size: 35px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   display: block;
  }
  .row::after {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   display: block;
  }
  header, footer {
   text-align: left;
   padding: 30px;
   margin: 0;

  }

  header h1 {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  nav {
   background-color: #ff00ff;
   position: relative;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
  }
  ul {
   /*overflow: scroll;*/
  }
  section{
   background-color: #ff0000;
   padding: 0 80px;
  }
  .col-3 {width: 25%;float: left;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;float: left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header><h1>HELL!<h1></header>
 <div class="row">
  <nav class="col-3">
   <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>end</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="col-9">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
  </p></section>
 </div>
 <footer><h3>HELL!<h3></footer>
```

So **First**: I want to know is there any way to do that without **js** and just with **CSS**?

*(or at least some of it.)*

**Second**: What's the best way to doing such things?

**Third**: How i suppose to fill height of document with a little element?

*(I actually killed my self, but couldn't find out!)*

**Fourth**: If you could give me a sample, i appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

‌

*PS: I know if i use*

```
.col-9 {float: right;}
```

*It makes it better, but it's not an option!*

Comment: Have you tried setting a px value to nav height? it wont show with 100% i think..

Comment: @Havihavi Thanks, but as you said, it won't work on every screen and mess with responsive pages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply some left margin to the container on the right when the nav is `fixed` since it gets removed from the flow.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var navs = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
  var heigh = $("header:first").outerHeight();
  var wid = $("nav:first").width();
  if (wid != $(window).width() && document.body.scrollTop >= heigh) {
    navs.style.position = "fixed";
    $("nav").css("top", "0");
    // Here is the fix
    $('.col-9').css('margin-left', wid);
  } else {
    navs.style.position = "relative";
    $('.col-9').css('margin-left', 0);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
header,
footer {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
ul {
  /*overflow: scroll;*/
}
section {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 0 80px;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>HELL!<h1></header>
 <div class="row">
  <nav class="col-3">
   <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>end</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="col-9">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
  </p></section>
 </div>
 <footer><h3>HELL!<h3></footer>
```

Comment: That's a cool trick, Thanks. but as you can see when we have a full header, either **scrollbar** on fixed element not works, or if it works because of the **height: 100%**, it won't show all of it.   and another problem is, if my fixed element has just 3 **<li>**, then in **relative** position it won't works right.   so if you could tell me how to fix these also, i appreciate it.

Comment: @ElSHEN I don't understand what you are asking. I thought I fixed the problem you mentioned in the question. Different problems should be separate questions.

Comment: Yes, you fixed it and i'm greatful. But you only fixed a part of it!  See this update on jsFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/9Lwo3mcb/1/) and you will understand my other problem. (actually i described it in **First** post *Third problem*).

Comment: @ElSHEN At Stack Overflow, questions are supposed to be helpful to other users, which means that they should be about a single problem. Explaining 4 different problems will create an unwieldy answer that is not likely to be helpful to others. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: **Update:** I know and sorry about that. i'll make another topic for that one. Thanks again.